# Highlight first row of kendo-grid

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-grid

I would like to highlight (or select) the first row of a kendo-grid. I need to get the first row in a typescript function and add ' `k-state-selected`'. The row doesn't have a unique id (except '`ng-reflect-logical-row-index="1"`'). What is the best approach/ implementation to either select (fake a row click, so the row is automatically selected) or highlight the first row.

Comment: CSS `tr:first-child { background-color: red }` ... ?

Comment: @Stavm I only want to select the first row in a certain situation, so I need to handle it in typescript.

Answer (score -1):

Kendo has a directive that allows you to add a class to a row based on callback.

CSS:

```
.k-grid tr.selected { background-color: yellow; }
```

HTML:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridData" [rowClass]="rowCallback"></kendo-grid>
```

TS:

```
public rowCallback(context: RowClassArgs) {
   if (context.index == 0) return 'selected';
}
```

[Check this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lgewov?file=app/app.component.ts)

for more information refer to their official [documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-selectablesettings).

Comment: Thanks for the sample code, but it doesn't work as expected. I want to set the current selected row of the grid, so it automatically highlights the row (using the default grid scss). After manually selecting a different row, the new row should be highlighted.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to highlight the first row of your `kendo Grid`, you can try the following:
In my example, the trigger is on page load. And, it is in jquery. Just convert it to typescript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var grid = $("#gridname").data("kendoGrid");
grid.select("tr:eq(1)");
})
```

See reference: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Kiril/Ocace